# Is there a relativily simple way to determine state of charge (SoC) for LiFePO4 batteries?

Tags: charging, lifepo4, state-of-charge, discharging

I'm searching for information regarding this matter and I can only find academic papers. I am wondering if anyone knows of any (more accurate or less accurate) way to evaluate the state of charge for batteries with LifePo4 chemistry. Prefer something simple that could be implements using a microcontroller.

Comment: There are ICs called "fuel gauge" that can estimate the SoC.

Comment: LiFePO4 is particularly difficult because it's voltage curve is so flat between about 90% and 10%. Look for "coulomb counting" solutions in @EugeneSh.'s fuel gauge ICs. Counting the charge out, and counting it back in.

Comment: Any more or less accurate than what?